# I get an error when i run this sql query for foreign key

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE module
(
    title VARCHAR(255),
    course_code INT(255),
    lecturer VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(course_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(lecturer)REFERENCES(name)
);
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 32: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(name)
)' at line 7
```

Comment: Which line is line 32? Are you missing a comma between `FOREIGN KEY` and `REFERENCES`?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the table name after **REFERENCES**

```
CREATE TABLE module ( title VARCHAR(255), course_code INT(255), lecturer VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY(course_code), FOREIGN KEY(lecturer) REFERENCES table(name) );
```